# Is low-level / embedded systems programming hard for software developers?

Tags: embedded, hardware, firmware

Given my background as a generalist, I can cover much of the area from analog electronics to writing simple applications that interface to a RDBMS backend.

I currently work in a company that develops hardware to solve industry-specific problems.  We have an experienced programmer that have written business apps, video games, and a whole bunch of other stuff for PC's.  But when I talk to him about doing low-level programming, he simultaneously express interest and also doubt/uncertainty about joining the project.

Even when talking about PC's, he seems to be more comfortable operating at the language level than the lower-level stuff (instruction sets, ISR's).  Still, he's a smart guy, and I think he'd enjoy the work once he is over the initial learning hump.  But maybe that's my own enthusiasm for low-level stuff talking...  If he was truly interested, maybe he would already have started learning stuff in that direction?

Do you have experience in making that software-to-hardware (or low-level software) transition?  Or, better yet, of taking a software only guy, and transitioning him to the low-level stuff?

Edit:

P.S. I'd love to hear from the responders what their own background is -- EE, CS, both?

Comment: A sidenote -- part of the reason I ask this is because if he is not going to be comfortable doing embedded stuff, we'll probably start scouting to add a "firmware guy".

Comment: As per your request - I'm a CE (computer engineer) that prefers the hardware/firmware side of development but is comfortable across the range - see my stackoverflow and/or linkedin profile.

Comment: I have a CIS degree circa 1985 and have worked across domains, from an Engineering firm doing PA&C to multiple [dead] web startups, Engineering to Financial Services.

Comment: Part of the problem is worrying about the execution time of every piece of code.

Answer (score 16):

At the end of the day, everything is an API.

Need to write code for an SPI peripheral inside a microcontroller?  Well, get the datasheet or hardware manual, and look at the SPI peripheral.  It's one, big, complex API.

The problem is that you have to understand the hardware and some basic EE fundamentals in order to comprehend what the API means.  The datasheet isn't written by and for SW developers, it was written for hardware engineers, and maybe software engineers.

So it's all from the perspective of the hardware (face it - the microcontroller company is a hardware company filled with hardware/asic engineers).

Which means the transition is by no means simple and straightforward.

But it's not difficult - it's just a slightly different domain.  If you can implement a study program, start off with [Rabbit Semiconductor](http://www.rabbit.com)'s kits.  There's enough software there so a SW guy can really dig in with little effort, and the HW is easy to deal with because everything is wrapped in nice little libraries. When they want to do something complex they can dig into the direct hardware access and fiddle at the lower level, but at the same time they can do some pretty cool things such as build little [webservers](http://www.rabbit.com/products/RCM4000/index.shtml) or [pan/tilt network cameras](http://www.rabbit.com/products/Camera_Interface_App_Kit/).  There are other companies with similar offerings, but Rabbit is really focused on making hardware easy for software engineers.

Alternately, get them into the Android platform.  It looks like a unix system to them, until they want to do something interesting, and then they'll have the desire to attack that little issue and they'll learn about the hardware.

If you really want to jump in the deep end, go with an [arduino kit](http://www.arduino.cc/) - cheap, free compilers and libraries, pretty easy to start off with, but you have to hook wires up to do something interesting, which might be too big of a hurdle for a reluctant software engineer.  But a little help and a few nudges in the right direction and they will be absolutely thrilled to have a little LED display that wibbles* like the nightrider lights...

-Adam

*Yes, that's a technical engineering term.

Comment: IMHO, low-level APIs are far easier to deal with and understand than some web Leviathan. It tells you *exactly* what to do, what's allowed and when. You need to deal with bytes and bits (and bitmasks), but that's about it.

Answer (score 9):

The best embedded programmers I've worked with are EE trained and learned SW on the job. The worst embedded developers are recent CS graduates who think SW is the only way to solve a problem. I like to think of embedded programming as the bottom of the SW pyramid.   It's a stable abstraction layer/foundation that makes life easy for the app developers.

Comment: Embedded system design requires an understanding of both hardware and software issues.  A frustrating amount of hardware seems to be designed by people who have little understanding of what things are easy or difficult in software.  It's pretty common for devices to include hardware which may have been *intended* to be helpful, but ends up being a nuisance.  Suppose, for example, that a chip has a 48-bit counter which counts 32,768 times/second.  Having a read of the lower half latch the upper half may seem helpful, but unless one disables interrupts between low-half and high-half reads...

Comment: ...an attempt to read the timer may yield corrupt data if between the two reads an interrupt also reads the timer.  By contrast, if no such hardware existed, software would have to read the low half and high half, and then reread the low half to ensure it hasn't changed (restart the operation if it has), but such a procedure could be employed in both main-loop and interrupt contexts without the simultaneous reads interfering.

Answer (score 6):

"Hard" is an extremely relative term. If you're used to thinking in the tight, sometimes convoluted way you need to for small embedded code (for example, you're a driver developer), then certainly it's not "hard".

Not to "bash" (no pun intended) shell scripters, but if you write perl and shell scripts all day, then it might very well be "hard".

Likewise if you're a UI guy for Windows. It's a different kind of thinking.

Answer (score 5):

Why embedded development is "hard":

1) The context may switch to an interrupt between each machine instruction. Since high level language constructs may map to multiple assembly instructins, this might even be within a line of code, e.g. long var = 0xAAAA5555. If accessed in an interrupt service routine, in a 16 bit processore var might only be half set.

2) Visibility into the system is limited. You may not even have output to Hyperterm unless you write it yourself. Emulators don't always work that well or consistently (though they are way better than they used to be). You will have to know how to use oscilloscopes and logic analyzers.

3) Operations take time. For example, say your serial transmitter uses an interrupt to signal when it is time to send another byte. You could write 16 bytes to a transmit buffer, then clear interrupts and wonder why your message is never sent. Timing in general is a tricky part of embedded programming.

4) You are subject to subtle race conditions that occur only rarely and are very difficult to debug.

5) You have to read the manual. A lot. You can't make it work by fooling around. Sometimes 20 things have to be set up correctly to get what you are after.

6) The hardware doesn't always work or is easy to damage, and it takes a while to figure out that you broke it.

7) Software repairs in embedded systems are usually very expensive. You can't just update a web page. A recall can erase any profit you made on the device.

There are probably more but I've got this race condition to solve...

Answer (score 4):

This is very subjective I guess, his reasons could be many. But if he's like me, I know where he's coming from. Let me explain.

In my career I've dedicated 6 years to the telecom industry, working a lot with embedding SDK middleware into low-end mobile phones etc.

Most embedded environments I've experienced are like harsh weather for a programmer, you constantly have to overcome limitations in resources etc. Some might find this a challenge and enjoy it for the challenge itself, some might feel close to "the real stuff" - the hardware, some might feel it limits their creativity.

I'm the kind who feels it limits my creativity.

I enjoy being back in Windows desktop environment and flap my wings with elaborate class designs, stretch my legs a few clockcycles extra, use unnecessary amounts of memory for diagnostics etc.

On certain embedded units in the past, I hardly had support for fseek() (an ANSI C standard file function). If lucky, a "watchdog" could give clues to where something crashed. Not to mention the pain of communicating with the user in single-threaded preemptive swamps.

Well, you know what I'm getting at. In my opinion it's not necessarily hard, but it's quite a leap, with potentially little reuse of your current experience.

Regards

Robert

Answer (score 3):

There is a very real difference in mindset from user-level application development (ie, general purpose PC or Web applications) to hard deadline, real-time response application development (ie, the hardware/software interface).

Interrupts, instruction sets, context switching and hard resource constraints are relatively unknown to your average developer.  I'm assuming here that your 'average developer' is not an Electrical/Electronic or other Engineer by training.

The transition for this developer you mention may be well outside his comfort zone.  Some of us like stretching like that.  Others of us may have decided the view isn't worth the climb.

Likewise, folks who've been in the hardware area (ie, Engineers) often have difficulty with the assumptions and language of software development.

These are gross generalities, of course, but hopefully give some insight.

Answer (score 3):

He needs to be comfortable with the low-level stuff, but mostly for debugging and field issues. There is a serious learning curve depending on the architecture, but not impossible. On the other hand, the low-level code takes (in general) more time and debugging than higher-level code. So if you need to be going back to low-level all the time, then perhaps something isn't right in the design. Even for the embedded controls I've built, I spend the vast majority of time in high-level code. Although *when* you have issues, it is extremely advantageous to have a very good low-level knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

I am an EE turned Software Engineer.  I prefer programming low level.  Most software developers classically trained that I know do not want to operate at this level they want apis to call.  So for me it is a win win, I create the low level driver and api for them to use.  There is a "new" degree, at least new since I went to college, called Computer Engineer.  Hmm, it might be an electrical engineering degree not computer science, but it is a nice mix of software and digital hardware basics.  The individuals that I have worked with from this field are much more comfortable with low level.

If the individual is not comfortable or willing then place them somewhere where they are comfortable.  Let them do documentation or work on the user interface.  If all of the work at the company requires low level work then this individual needs to do it or find another job.  Dont sugar coat it.

I also think they will enjoy it once they get over the hump, the freedom you have at that level, not hindered by operating systems, etc.  Recently I witnessed a few co-workers experience for the first time seeing their software run under simulation.  Every net within the processor and other on chip peripherals.  No you dont have a table on a gui (debugger) showing the current state of the memory, you have to look at the memory bus, look for the address you are interested in, look for a read or write signal and the data bus.  I worry about the day that silicon arrives and they no longer have this level of visibility.  Will be like an addict in detox.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I cut my teeth on hardware when I started reading Popular Electronics at age 14 – this was BEFORE personal computers, in case you were wondering and if you weren’t well, you know anyway. lol

I’ve done the low level bit-bang stuff on the 8048/51 microprocessor, done PIC’s and some other single chip variations and of course Rabbit Semiconductor. (great if you're into C). That’s great (and fun) stuff; Yes, there is a different way of looking at things – not harder, but some of that information is a bit harder to come by as it isn’t as discussed as the software issues.  (Of course, this depends on the circle of friends with which you associate, eh).

But, having said all of this, I want to remind you of a technology that started to bridge the gap for programmers into the world of hardware and has since become a very MAJOR player and that is the .NET micro framework.    You can find information on this technology at the following;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/embedded/bb267253.aspx

It addresses some of the same issues that .NET web development addressed in that you can use some (quite a bit, actually) of your existing PC based knowledge in the new environments – Some caution, of course, as your target machine doesn’t have 4 GIG of RAM – it may only have 64K  (or less)

Starting in version 2.5 of the .NET micro framework, you have access to networking and web services – way kewl, eh?  It doesn’t stop there … Want to control the lights in your house?  How about a temp recording station?  All with the skills you already have.  Well, mostly -- Check out the link.

The SDK plugs into your VisualStudio IDE.  There are a number of “Development Kits” available for a very reasonable amount of cash – Now, what would normally take a big learning curve in components, building a circuit board and wiring up “stuff” can be done reasonably easy with a dev kit and some pretty simple code – Of course, you may need to do the occasional bit bang operation, but more and more sensor folks are providing .NET micro framework drivers – so, the hardware development may be closer than you think…

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is not any harder, it just requires a different knowledge set, different considerations.

Answer (score 1):

I like both. Embedded challenges me and really gets me going in a visceral way. Making something that affects the macro physical world is *very* satisfactory. But I've had to do a lot of catch up on the electrical/electronics end, since my bachelor's is in computer science. I've a pretty generalist background, where I studied ai, graphics, compilers, natural language, etc. Now I'm doing graduate work in embedded systems. The really tough part is adjusting to the lack of runtime facilities like an operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Low-level embedded programming also tends to include low-level debugging.  Which (in my experience) usually involves (at least) the use of an oscilloscope.  Unless your colleague is going to be happy spending at least some of the time in physical contact with the hardware and thinking in terms of microseconds and volts, I'd be tempted to leave them be.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed on the "hard" term is quite relative.

I would say different, as you would need to employ different development patterns that you won't use in other kind of environment.
The time constraint for instance could requires a learning curve.
However being curious, would be a quality for a developer, wouldn't be?

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that anyone with enough knowledge not to feel completely lost in an area (over the hump?) will enjoy the challenges of learning something new.

I myself would feel quite nervous being moving to the level of instruction sets etc as there is a huge amount of background knowledge needed to feel comfortable in the environment.

It may make a difference if you are able to support the developer in learning how to do this. Having someone there you can ask and talk through issue with is a huge help in that sort of domain change.

It may be worth having the developer assigned to a smaller project with others as a first step and see how that goes. If he expresses enthusiasm to try another project, things should flow on from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it depends on the way that they program in their chosen environment, and the type of embedded work that you're talking about.

Working on an embedded linux platform, say, is a far smaller jump than trying to write code on an 8 bit platform with no operating system at all.

If they are the type of person that has an understanding of what is going on underneath the api and environment that they are used to, then it won't be too much of a stretch to move into embedded development.

However, if their world view stops at the high level api that they've been using, and they have no concept of anything beneath that, they are going to have a really hard time.

As a (very) general statement if they are comfortable working on multithreaded applications they will probably be ok, as that shares some of the same issues of data volatility that you have when working on embedded projects.

With all of that said, I've seen more embedded programmers successfully working in PC development than I have the reverse. (of course I might not have seen a fair cross section)

Answer (score 0):

"But when I talk to him about doing low-level programming, he simultaneously express interest and also doubt/uncertainty about joining the project."  -- That means you let him try and you prepare to hire someone else in case he doesn't pass the learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

i began as a SW engineer i'm now HW one !
the important is to understand how it works and to be motivated !