# What can firmware engineers learn from software engineers?

Tags: embedded, firmware

Judging from my knowledge of the history of firmware engineering tools, practices etc.  It has consistently lagged behind the software engineering field by several years.  For example, as far as I can tell there is still a fair amount of debate in the firmware world as to whether C++ is actually worth using for our applications, and some C++ compilers are noticeably absent (microchip?!?).  I imagine that in large part this is due to the differences in requirements between firmware and software.  Again, judging from history, it seems its only a matter of time before the properly vetted tools and techniques make it into the firmware world.

What methods, tools, best practices etc that modern software engineers use regularly, could firmware engineers also leverage to improve their craft?

Specifically I'm thinking along the following axes (but don't let them limit you):

- Improving code cleanliness/maintainability
- Reducing defect introduction and improving detection
- Improving documentation
- Requirements management
- Improving reusability

I'd also love to see embedded shops answer or comment on the answers to provide feedback about theoretical feasibility or, better yet, personal experiences.

**UPDATE**
I'm especially interested in jumping ahead of the curve a little bit.  So relatively new stuff that has been vetted reasonably well (works well for most people), like C++, TDD, etc.  What do you use all the time and love?

**UPDATE 2**
I'm getting a lot of good general programming advice in the answers so far, which is great, but I'm really looking for more unconventional approaches that have proved successful for people.  I'm trying to tease out the Agile practitioners, the TDDers, and the rest of you who have tried stuff and seen it pay off in spades or fail horribly.  As a software engineer has there been a tool or practice that you've adopted in the past several years that has had a remarkably positive or negative impact?

Comment: What can they learn? Programming :p

Comment: Loosely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231543/is-low-level-embedded-systems-programming-hard-for-software-developers

Comment: C++ on microchip? I'd settle for a malloc implementation in the their C18 library for starters.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What can firmware engineers learn from software engineers? Plenty!

I am surprised at how similar firmware development is practiced today as it was 25 years ago when we first started using C for embedded development. C was a big step forward from assembler, but there are many more lessons learned that firmware engineers can and should learn from.  Yeah, some of the tools are better, but many practices are stuck in the 70s and 80s.

Embedded software development does add some additional challenges on top of the challenges faced by non-embedded developers. But all the principles and practices that skilled software developers use are applicable to embedded development. BTW: It's not just the embedded software developers that are not up on these state of the art practices, but many non-embedded software developers as well.

The people I know and have met doing firmware are by and large a very skilled group, working to solve difficult problems.  Unfortunately, for whatever reason, many have not kept up with developments in the software world. I think it has to do with an imaginary barrier erected by firmware engineers.

Embedded and non-embedded developers speak different languages, but solve similar problems.  Keeping embedded code independent from a hardware device is essentially the same as keeping  application code independent of the UI or database.  The underlying principles are the same.

Here are a few things that I think embedded developers should pay more attention to. Some of these principles and practices can be used right out of the box, while others might need a little adjustment to deal with the embedded challenges. If you want to substitute the word firmware for software below, go ahead, I don't really distinguish between the two.

#### Dependency Management

Dependencies between modules must be managed. Dependency from software to hardware is a special case that must be actively managed by the embedded software developer. If you don't manage the dependency, it will manage you.

In practice this means that only a limited subset of the software modules should have knowledge of the underlying hardware (and operating system).  As the hardware evolves, and it always does, the investment in the hardware independent code can be preserved.
See my [ah ha!](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.JamesGrenning.TransformingIdea) moment.

Robert Martin has written extensively on the SOLID design principles.  Embedded developers should get to know them and apply them to their designs.

- S-Singled Responsibility Principle
- O-Open Closed Principles
- L-Liskov Substitution Principle
- I-Interface Segregation Principle
- D-Dependency Inversion Principle

These principles lead to designs that better stand the test of time.  The SOLID principles encourage creating cohesive and independent modules. They are build on object oriented ideas, but can be applied to C.  We have to stop the function-call data-structure free-for-all that is all too common in embedded C code.

#### C++ and OO languages

Why can't you use C++ and OO?   Because they are too slow, or too big.  What are the facts? C++ is a big, and mysterious language, but you don't have to use all of it. Take a look at [Why are you still using C?](http://www.renaissancesoftware.net/papers/14-papers/51-stillusingc.html)

C++ makes up for some of the problems that C does not help much with like:

- Encapsulation and information hiding
- Programming to interfaces
- Substitutable objects
- Ad-hoc initialization

C++ can be used effectively for embedded development.  Well you do need a C++ compiler, and the headroom. Maybe that is not possible in your world, or maybe it is the cost of doing business.  Start by learning:

- classes - these are structs with member functions as well as member data.
- constructors - these make it possible to get initialization right, all the time.
- destructors - if you learn constructors, you must also learn destructors to keep the universe in balance.
- inheritance - use this mainly for defining interfaces that contain only pure virtual functions.  Interfaces provide important dependency breaks and flexibility points. These are usually unjustly discouraged in embedded.  There should be no mystery or prejudice here; virtual functions are function pointers under the hood. The alternative to effective use of interfaces is complex conditional logic, something that embedded C programs usually have too much of.

If embedded developers used those parts of C++ they could build more flexible design and not incur a high cost.

#### Test Driven Development

This might be the biggest game changer. I am glad to see other posts mention it too.  TDD can help prevent defects now and in the future.  To see why TDD might help take a look at [The Physics of TDD](http://www.renaissancesoftware.net/blog/archives/16).

Embedded does present some unique challenges for TDD.  For example, TDD requires an extremely fast incremental edit/compile/link/run cycle.  For many embedded developers this means careful **Dependency Management** and running unit test first on the target. See more about  [adapting TDD for Embedded](http://www.renaissancesoftware.net/papers/14-papers/39-test-driven-development-for-embedded-software.html).

With TDD, you are creating code that is thoroughly tested. The comprehensive automated test coverage acts as a safety net, allowing code to be changed safely as requirements change.  Unintended consequences are immediately discovered.

Also, having the tests that [you get almost for free](http://www.renaissancesoftware.net/blog/archives/46), allow you to fearlessly refactor your code...

#### Continuous Refactoring

Code is written once, but read many times. Then it is changed and tweaked, leading to designs that degrade over time. If developers do not continually refactor to keep the code clean, it turns into a mess.  Maybe some of you are dealing with that mess. TDD's automated tests enable low-cost and low-risk refactoring.

#### Continuous Integration

Automate your build process.  Have it run with every workspace checkin.  This is a challenge with the heterogenous tools sets often needed to get the compiled code into the target, but it is still the right goal.

The sooner the embedded developer knows that a change is somehow incompatible with some other work, the faster it can be repaired and the less time will be spend in painful merges.

#### Incremental Delivery

Find ways to split the work so that large painful integrations can be avoided, and design ideas can be tried early. Avoid splitting along architectural lines, focus on delivering slices of visible functionality.

#### Collaboration

Embedded developers! get out of there cubes and work together.  How can you get better when you only see your own code?  How can you improve when you are the expert on technology XXX, have mastered it and don't get an opportunity to work in different areas.

There is lots to learn out there.  Are you responsible for being all you can

Comment: thanks James, that's exactly the type of answer I was looking for.  Hopefully this post can serve as a reference for others.

Comment: The above list could also answer "What is a list of practices any software engineer should have in his toolbox?"  I didn't read anything in this answer that tells why it applies specifically to embedded software engineers... other than the subjective opinion of James that most embedded developers he knows use practices from earlier decades.  In my experience, the answer above is a list of practices that are the norm; with the exception that the team I was on knew exactly why we should choose C over C++. We investigated, measured and concluded that C was the better choice for our project.

Comment: Glad to hear you are doing all those things.  Though I am surprised you think these practices are the norm.  I don't see it as the norm. Some embedded developers doing these practices, but far fewer are.  BTW: not the norm outside of embedded.  

Yes, we are in the realm of opinion.  My opinion is based on how few people I find at places like embedded systems conference that have an understanding of these practices, and how few articles and books describe these ideas applied to embedded. I love hearing about more that are doing this stuff, but it is certainly not the norm IMO.

Answer (score 16):

I have worked both as an embedded software engineer and as software developer. Being there in both worlds, I have learned that no matter how little resources your system has and what language you are programming, there are many things that can make your life easier.

The first thing is the tools you are using. In embedded software you only deal with the compiler/linker most of the time. There are more than these. Diff tools, regular expressions a scripting language, documentation tools save you a lot of time.

Another thing is code quality. One needs to follow style conventions, go through regular refactoring cycles and in general have in mind that code reading is done more often than code writing and it really pays to have more readable code.

Some times in embedded software we miss the design phase altogether. Embedded projects are usually not so big as desktop/server ones, but that is not excuse for not doing a proper design.

Software needs to be tested on its own and not only as part of the device. It really saves a lot of time to build a software simulator of your system, just for testing that the software meets the required specifications. It is much more expensive to do so when the whole thing, hardware and software is ready.

Comment: +1 for coding conventions. I almost take that for granted if you are serious about coding.

Comment: +1 for "code reading is done more often than code writing"

Comment: +1 for working in firmware and software

Answer (score 8):

- Source control
- Unit testing (TDD)
- Continuous integration (or nightly builds)
- Bug tracking

Firmware engineers I've worked with don't do any of these.

Unit testing may not apply very will to all kinds of firmware. I image its harder to unit test something when it's running on physical hardware. Depends if you have emulators available I suppose.

Comment: I think a nightly build of firmware might be a little expensive.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: If doing firmware is part of you company's business you decide whether you want nightly builds the same way as usual software companies decide. Firmware is software.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I'm assuming they can just compile the software and run the unit tests in some kind of emulator. Obviously I don't mean physically build the hardware each night =:)

Comment: It would be pretty cool, though, to have a new iPod or cell phone on your desk each morning, fresh off the Reality Printer.  =)

Comment: @MusiGenesis: We'll get there one day - http://reprap.org/bin/view/Main/WebHome

Comment: Re unit testing: write your code to be cross-platform, then unit test it on a PC.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming by "firmware engineers" you mean "embedded software engineers", then my answer would be: they **are** software engineers, so they should - where possible - be doing the same things as any other software engineer.

Obviously, writing software for embedded systems requires some different skills, such as a detailed knowledge of the target processor, and being able to deal with limited resources (compared to a PC or similar).

As others have mentioned, unit testing is complicated by the fact that this may have to be done on a simulator running on a PC, which while very useful, can never be a substitute for thorough testing of the real system - especially given the asynchronous nature of events that an embedded system is subject to.

One of my concerns as to why embedded software may appear to be "behind the curve" is because software engineering - and as part of that, embedded software - is not generally taught in any depth on electronic engineering degrees. Given how much of an electronic engineer's career is likely to be spent coding nowadays, this seems like a massive oversight.

Fortunately, there are those who are trying to make up for this. I'd strongly recommend reading the articles of Jack Ganssle (on [his website](http://www.ganssle.com/), and in his regular column on [embedded.com](http://www.embedded.com/columns/archive/?content_type=bp)).

In addition, [MISRA-C](http://www.misra.org.uk/) was created a while ago to try to avoid common sources of bugs in C software for the automotive industry, and his since been adopted by many in the embedded software world. Add a static analysis checker like [PC-Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/), and you've already gone some way to improving your code.

The tools vendors have also not helped, in many cases by creating their own IDEs, when perhaps it would have been better to concentrate on the compiler and debugger, and leave the IDE to others, e.g. Eclipse.

Incidentally, for more on the non-use of C++ in embedded systems see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812717/is-there-any-reason-to-use-c-instead-of-c-for-embedded-development/815197#815197).

Finally: because firmware engineers are software engineers, we face many of the same issues, challenges and concerns, so we should use the same resources; after all, there's plenty of them around, and you're reading one of them!

Some of the other websites I frequent include:

- [Stack Overflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) and podcast
- [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)
- [Talk About Quality](http://talkaboutquality.wordpress.com/)
- [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/)
- [Secret Geek](http://www.secretgeek.net/)
- [Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/)
- A different [Stack Overflow blog](http://www.embeddedgurus.net/stack-overflow/); this is one is dedicated to embedded systems.

**EDIT:** In response to Gabe's comment, "what tools should we be looking to adapt?", a couple of examples spring to mind:

**Compiler-independent IDEs:** There are [plenty of IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951516/a-good-c-ide) for C, but as far as I can tell, few of them can be used to their few potential without a compatible compiler. I'd like to see both the compiler developers and the IDE developers converge so that, ideally, any compiler can be used with any IDE.

In the absence of a compatible compiler, I'd like to be able to use PC-Lint (or equivalent) as my "official" compiler with an IDE of my choice.

**Simulation and modelling:** Simulation tools like [Simulink](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/simulink/) allow simulation, modelling and testing of software for the PC and some higher-end embedded processors. Tools like this would be just as useful for the smaller chips, so it would nice to see them extended to that area of the market.

PS: Jack Ganssle's column this week is entitled, "[What makes embedded different?](http://www.embedded.com/columns/technicalinsights/218600620;jsessionid=IFHSBBXMBKMASQSNDLRSKH0CJUNN2JVN)", and so is (loosely) related to the question above.

Comment: Thanks for the links steve, I'm always looking for insightful knowledge sources on software engineering.  I agree that embedded software engineers tackle a lot of the same issues as the rest of the software engineering world, but I think the mix of constraints really sets the trades apart.  Tools must be adapted to the embedded world, they can't just be raw copied.  My question really becomes then, what tools should we be looking to adapt?

Comment: accepted for links, the link to Jack's article on differentiators between the fields, and the suggested tools to adapt

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what degree of software is considered firmware (bios, driver, or utilities), but the standard complaint I hear is that the UI is non-standard. Realizing that UI matters and that it should follow some standards or tradition would be good thing.

As far as C++ goes, it's understandable to hesitate to get into it because there's a lot of overhead compared to C. C is almost like an assembly language with libc, whereas in C++ even a simple function call can be virtual. Implementing the full C++ runtime cannot be that easy given the complexity of the language.

There are too many things to list in terms of software development "best practices" (I hate that words). Why not start with [The Joel Test: 12 Steps to Better Code.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)

> The Joel Test
>
> 1. Do you use source control?
> 2. Can you make a build in one step?
> 3. Do you make daily builds?
> 4. Do you have a bug database?
> 5. Do you fix bugs before writing new code?
> 6. Do you have an up-to-date schedule?
> 7. Do you have a spec?
> 8. Do programmers have quiet working conditions?
> 9. Do you use the best tools money can buy?
> 10. Do you have testers?
> 11. Do new candidates write code during their interview?
> 12. Do you do hallway usability testing?

Comment: on the C++ note, you definitely have to know what you're doing, but written carefully, you can gain a lot without losing much (if any) efficiency.

I realize that an exhaustive list of software development "best practices" is impractical.  I'm more looking for relatively new developments that could prove useful in the embedded world.

Answer (score 3):

Let me first address an assumption in your question.  The assumption is that embedded software engineers (ESE) do not know or are not aware of modern software engineering practices and need to learn new practices.  This assumption should be tossed out right away. I believe you would find the same statistical distribution of ESEs who keep their skills and techniques up-to-date as non-embedded SEs.

So, maybe your question becomes an array of questions like:

1. Why do ESEs use a separate code editor and a command line compiler and not an IDE?
2. Why is C preferred over C++ in the majority of embedded projects?
3. Why isn't there as much experimentation in programming practices in the embedded world?

The following paragraphs answer these questions.

1. ESEs usually use a specific code editor because it is a personal preference or it is what is used by his/her company.  IDEs are not as common because ESEs work very closely to the silicon and not all chip manufacturers develop an IDE for their line of chips.  Only the chips that achieve highest market penetration, such as ARM, have enough momentum to warrant the development of IDE-based tools. Furthermore, an IDE doesn't provide as much of an assistance to the ESE as it  does to, say, a desktop developer.  IDEs provide help with making the glue to the GUI or code-completion for large APIs; neither of which is commonly found or as standard as in the embedded world.
2. I'm sure there are better write-ups as to why C is preferred over C++ in embedded systems than I can make up on the spot.  The short of it is that you use what works.  C works and is more common (more programmers know C than C++). The other reason might be that the OO methodology was devised to help programmers solve large problems by abstracting the solution into manageable conceptual objects. In the embedded world, the problems are usually whittled down to as small a problem (and solution) as possible so that the embedded system becomes more reliable by having a smaller code base.
3. There is less experimentation by ESEs because an embedded product, in general, must be far less prone to error and have higher reliability than a desktop program.  This means a rigid application of well-proven practices and more time spent in testing.  Why?  Because often there is no feasible path to upgrade the firmware of an embedded device; it's either impossible due to the system being deployed beyond reach or implausible because of the cost of updating millions of devices.

In conclusion, **ESEs use tools and practices that best suit their needs just as non-embedded SEs do.**  As a practicing ESE, I believe the embedded software  discipline is far more different than my non-ESE friends believe it is.  So the apparent disparity of programming practices is not a matter of ESEs needing to learn modern practices, but non-ESEs needing to understand how different embedded programming is.

Comment: I think you may have missed the focus of my question.  I did not mean to claim that ESEs are not keeping up to date with their skills.  I am simply curious to hear about some of the successful tools/methods/etc. that the SEs use and love, but haven't yet made it over the divide into the ESE world.  The motivation for this is to search for tools/methods/etc that could be adapted and leveraged by the ESEs so that we can take advantage of the extensive trial and error that's already been done by the SEs.

Answer (score 3):

**Automated testing**
Do not visually scan your simulation outputs to check is everything is OK. You need comprehensive automated test because you are always going to miss something in that mass of waveforms.

**Version Control**
You are not going to remember what was the working version. Use Version control software so you know what to program that board with.

**Bug Tracking**
Your going to forget sooner or later. A bug log should contain the version(see Version Control) in which the problem was first detected and the version in which it was fixed.

**Whoops** I thought you meant firmware as in FPGA but the same is true for embedded software. If you already have these processes in place great else forget about `unconventional approaches` until get the basics right.

Comment: assume for the time being that stuff is nailed down already.  How can we do better?

Answer (score 2):

Firmware Engineering is quite broad. From PIC to DSP they all have varying degree of physical resources. These days DSPs are quite powerful (comparable with the CPUs ~5years old), can support large amount of memory etc. But then again you have PICS which operate with several kilobytes. More meagre the resources, the programmer has to use ingenious hacks to get the most out of the device. And the focus is on 'get it to work' rather than 'write elegant code'.

What I would like to see is good project management tools that incorporate code as well as documents as you have to refer to lots of datasheets, design docs which are scattered around the network and on email blobs etc..

I would also like to see better dev tools for DSPs (TI: please hand over CCS to some one good at making IDEs) , and more library makers using C++ (I'm looking at you ATEME) to build better libraries.

And also hardware engineers to have a better appreciation of Object Orientation rather than blurt out, 'if it's C++ it's going to be slow'.

Comment: +1 for the comment about better dev tools. You think TI CCS is bad? It's a beautiful development environment compared to what you can get for programming Microchip dsPICs. MPLAB is awful, and Microchip doesn't even offer a C++ compiler, only a C compiler. The TI C++ compiler at least is pretty darn good for the 28xx series of DSPs. But I think they should all migrate towards Eclipse... it's a headache to remember different IDE features, and refactoring is kick-ass on Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit out of context.
A short reference to a firmware column at [**Embedded**](http://www.embedded.com/),

- [**Bug-killing standards for firmware coding**](http://www.embedded.com/design/opensource/216200567)
- Some pages forward into the article, [**Ten Bug-Killing Rules**](http://www.embedded.com/design/opensource/216200567?pgno=4)

I have always found good articles on firmware engineering at Embedded.
Which probably many interested in this question have too...

Comment: thanks nik, I have also used them frequently as a resource.